# What happened to algebraic/combinatorial probability theory?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, education, math-history

Historically, the study of probability was a mostly algebraic area, with strong emphasis on combinatorics. Calculus and other predecessors of analysis were rarely used in the study of probability. Now, though, probability theory is almost always considered as a subset of analysis. So, in a nutshell, what happened? Why did probability theory cross over from algebra to analysis?

Comment: Discrete random variables aren't sufficient for many applications of probability theory.

Comment: You could say that discrete-time stochastic processes are combinatorial or algebraic in nature, but continuous-time stochastic processes require heavy measure theory.  Compare the classic early 50s books of Feller (volume 1) and Doob.  The first is pretty combinatorial, the second a massive excursion into measure theory.

Comment: In a nutshell, 1933 happened, with Kolmogorov' *Grundbegriffe der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung*.